# How to best use an email log on a separate Google Apps email address

Tags: gmail, login

I'm using Google Apps and I'm receiving several emails per minute which are logging emails of services that I have written software for. Using the Gmail web interface, I find this exteremly effective, as it allows me to see a log of a service under a label, as well as to search specific logs for text very fast (all without having to implement the log viewer in the software).

However, what I currently cannot do is:

- share the log with someone without sharing my Inbox
- use vacation auto-reply

I'm looking for easy and fast ways to access this mailbox, for example: starting an anonymous Chrome tab and logging in or similar in Firefox or some other way to script the log in into Gmail (even with a different browser) without logging me out somewhere else. I'm using both Chrome and Firefox on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Chrome, you can enable a different profile that will automatically be signed into that Google account:

1. Go to the Wrench icon, and click Settings...
2. Scroll down to the "Users" section, and click the "Add new user" button.
3. Chrome will show a new Window that will have a small icon in the upper left or right (left for Linux/Windows, right for Mac).  It should bring you to a page that prompts you to enter your Google account email and password.  Do so with your "logging" account.
4. Again, go to the Wrench, click Settings...
5. Under "On Startup", change the radio button to "Open a specific set of pages"
6. Click on the "Set Pages" link, and add "https://mail.google.com/" .

Now, you should always see an icon appear at the upper left (or right) of your chrome windows. Click on the icon and choose the new user you created whenever you want to see your logging.

Answer (score 0):

There is clearly no way in which Google will allow this. I do not think that there would be any Crome Extension or Firefox Plug-in to do this kind of stuff - it is a kind of Privacy Violation and Security Breach.